# Given a sequence of alphanumeric strings, output the length of the largest string

Tags: bash

Given a sequence of alphanumeric strings, output the length of the largest string containing at least one alphabet and one digit. If no such string is present output 0.

Should be using Bash

Comment: where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Can you give you a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell use what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please, post some sample dataset with the expected output and some shot at solving the ptoblem on your own. Don't post them as comments or images but edit them to the original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { map[0]="" } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /[[:digit:]]/ && $i ~ /[[:alpha:]]/) { map[length($i)]=$i }  } } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for (i in map) { len=i } print len}' <<< "this sfdsf fdgdf 6gdfgg 56gdfggf67dfgdg"
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
             map[0]=""                                               # Initialise an array map with a 0 string length index
           } 
           { 
             for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {                                    # Loop through each work in the sequence of string
               if ($i ~ /[[:digit:]]/ && $i ~ /[[:alpha:]]/) { 
                  map[length($i)]=$i                                 # If the word matches a digit and it matches a alpha character, add to the map array with the length of the word as the index and the word the value
               }  
             } 
            } 
        END { 
              PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";                   # At the end of processing the sequence, set the array ordering
              for (i in map) { 
                len=i                                                 # Loop through the array setting len to the index
              } 
              print len                                               # Print len, (the highest length)
             }' <<< "this sfdsf fdgdf gdfgg 56gdfggf67dfgdg"
```